# How can I use sed to match a certain word and then wrap that word with quotes?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use `sed` to replace all of occurrences of

`{% url something arg1 arg2 ... argN %}` with

`{% url 'something' arg1 arg2 ... argN %}` (notice the quotation marks)

But only if `something` is not already quoted!

I tried the following:

`s/{% url [^']\(\S\+\)/{% url '\1'/`

but that captures the first character in `something`. So the result would be:

`{% url 'omething' arg1 arg2 ... argN %}`

If I do this instead:

`s/{% url[^']\(\S\+\)/{% url '\1'/`

Then it doesn't correctly exclude the occurrences in which `something` is already quoted.

What is the correct way to do what I mean?

Comment: Is it possible to use another language, namely with a support for `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` ?

Comment: Why not just capture [^'] too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
# test data
cat file
{% url something arg1 arg2 ... argN %} with
{% url 'foobar' arg1 arg2 ... argN %}

# sed command
sed -E "s/(\{% url )([^'][^' ]+) /\1'\2' /" file
{% url 'something' arg1 arg2 ... argN %} with
{% url 'foobar' arg1 arg2 ... argN %}
```

Comment: Yes you are right @John1024 `([^'][^' ]+)` is more correct as you suggested.